# Fastest way to serialize and compress a hashmap (object) in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, serialization, compression, brotli

What is the fastest way to serialize and compress a javascript hashmap (object) in NodeJS 12+? I'm trying to find the fastest combination of serialization and compression methods to transform a javascript object into binary data.

The number of possible combinations is 100+, my goal is a pre-study to **choose several best options** for final benchmark.

**Input**: an object having arbitrary keys, so some [really fast](https://github.com/Adelost/javascript-serialization-benchmark) serialization methods like [AVSC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/avsc) cannot be used. Assume that the object has 30 key-value pairs, example:

```
{
  "key-one": 2,
  "key:two-random-text": "English short text, not binary data.",
  ... 28 more keys
}
```

No need to support serialization of Date, Regex etc.

**Serialization** only schemaless serialization formats can be taken into account, like JSON or BSON. [V8.serialize](https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html#v8_v8_serialize_value) is an interesting option, probably it's fast because it's native. [Compress-brotli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress-brotli) package added it's support for some reason, but did not provide a benchmark or highlighted it as a recommended option.

**Compression** Probably only fastest methods should be [considered](https://peazip.github.io/fastest-compression-zip-deflate-benchmark.html). Not sure if [brotli](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brotli/vignettes/brotli-2015-09-22.pdf) is a perfect choice because according to wiki it's strong in compressing JS, CSS and HTML because expects "keywords" in input. Native nodejs support is preferred.

I've found a [helpful research](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2019/12/06/json-compression-alternative-binary-formats-and-compression-methods/#:%7E:text=Brotli%20works%20really%2C%20really%20well,to%20any%20modern%20major%20browser.) for a similar use case (I'm planning to compress via lambda and store in S3), but their data originates in JSON, opposite to my case.

Comment: just gzip the json, it's native

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [lz4](https://pypi.org/project/lz4/) for fast compression.

Comment: Thanks for pointing, it's definitely designed for speed https://catchchallenger.first-world.info/wiki/Quick_Benchmark:_Gzip_vs_Bzip2_vs_LZMA_vs_XZ_vs_LZ4_vs_LZO